# Squareup not loading iframes for Waterfox/IE11, Silent Error

Tags: square-connect, square

I've confirmed that Square's code now works with pages served as `application/xhtml+xml` and with the exact same code Chrome works though Waterfox (and Firefox) do not load the iframes for the form fields. I've verified this in the DOM (they're not hidden, the original placeholder elements are still there).

- Chrome requests the `f.js` file, Gecko browsers do not.
- The placeholder elements that the `iframe` elements are supposed to replace are still in the DOM.
- There are no error messages in the developer consoles in Waterfox 56, Firefox 64, Chrome 71 or Opera 12.1.
- I've disabled prototypes for testing.
- The browsers yield the same results for local and live testing.
- The `var sqPaymentForm = new SqPaymentForm(...);` object is different for Gecko browsers.

What Gecko has for `sqPaymentForm`:

- _handleDomContentLoaded
- clientController
- env
- errorLogger
- options

What Gecko *does not have* for `sqPaymentForm`:

- build
- _handleDomContentLoaded

Ironically I have limited access to IE11. I won't have time to setup the Mac until later on Friday mid-afternoon. Here are a couple cropped screenshots:

**Firefox 56**
[image: Firefox 56 Square not loading iframe form fields]

**IE 11**
[image: IE 11 Square not loading iframe form fields]

Here is the `sqPaymentForm` object (with obvious basic obfuscation):

```
var sqPaymentForm = new SqPaymentForm(
{
 applicationId: 'sandbox-abc',
 locationId: 'CBASEE123',
 applePay: {elementId: 'sq-apple-pay'},
 callbacks:
 {
  methodsSupported: function (methods)
  {
   if (methods.applePay && methods.applePay === true) {var element = document.getElementById('pay-button-area'); element.style.display = 'block';}
  },
  cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData)
  {
   if (errors)
   {
    var errorDiv = document.getElementById('errors');
    errorDiv.innerHTML = '';
    errors.forEach(function(error) {var p = document.createElement('p'); p.innerHTML = error.message; errorDiv.appendChild(p);});
   }
   else
   {
    id_('card-nonce-submit').setAttribute('disabled','true');
    id_('card_brand').value = cardData.card_brand;
    id_('cc_end').value = cardData.last_4;
    id_('cc_month').value = cardData.exp_month;
    id_('cc_year').value = cardData.exp_year;
    id_('zip').value = cardData.billing_postal_code;
    document.getElementById('card-nonce').value = nonce;
    payment_submit();
   }
  },
  unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {console.log('Error: unsupported browser.');},
  createPaymentRequest: function ()
  {
   return {currencyCode: 'USD', countryCode: 'US', requestShippingAddress: false, total: {amount: '1.00', label: 'JAB Creations', pending: false},lineItems: [{amount: '1.00', label: 'Subtotal', pending: false},{amount: '0.00', label: 'Tax', pending: false}]};
  },
 },
 cardNumber: {elementId: 'sq-card-number', placeholder: '0000 0000 0000 0000'},
 cvv: {elementId: 'sq-cvv', placeholder: 'CVV'},
 env: {},
 excludeCanvas: {},
 expirationDate: {elementId: 'sq-expiration-date', placeholder: 'MM/YY'},
 inputClass: 'sq-input',
 inputStyles: [
 // Because this object provides no value for mediaMaxWidth or mediaMinWidth, these styles apply for screens of all sizes, unless overridden by another/ input style below.
 {
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  color: ($('input[type="text"]').length > 0) ? window.getComputedStyle($('input[type="text"]')[0]).getPropertyValue('color') : '#fff',
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',//localStorage.getItem('input_style_font-family')
  fontSize: '18px',//localStorage.getItem('input_style_font-size'),
  fontWeight: 'bold',//localStorage.getItem('input_style_font-weight')
  lineHeight: '18px',//localStorage.getItem('input_style_line-height'),
  padding: '0'
 },
 // These styles are applied to inputs ONLY when the screen width is 400px
 // or smaller. Note that because it doesn't specify a value for padding,
 // the padding value in the previous object is preserved.
 {
  mediaMaxWidth: '400px',
  fontSize: '48px',
  lineHeight: '18px'
 }],
 maxTouchPoints: {},
 inputEventReceived: function(inputEvent)
 {
  switch (inputEvent.eventType)
  {
   case 'focusClassAdded':
   // Handle as desired
   console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('sq-input--focus')[0]);
   break;

   case 'focusClassRemoved':
   // Handle as desired
   console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('sq-input--focus')[0]);
   break;

   case 'errorClassAdded':
   // Handle as desired
   break;

   case 'errorClassRemoved':
   // Handle as desired
   break;

   case 'cardBrandChanged':
   // Handle as desired
   break;

   case 'postalCodeChanged':
   // Handle as desired
   break;
  }
 },
 postalCode: {elementId: 'sq-postal-code', placeholder: 'Postal Code'}
});
```

How do I get the other browsers to load the iframe form fields? This certainly seems like a bug and I'm happy to report back any information that would help with troubleshooting.

---

**Update 1**

Running `for (i in SqPaymentForm) {console.log('SqPaymentForm.'+i);}` reveals the `SqPaymentForm` object in a different light. The `SqPaymentForm.isSupportedBrowser` function returns `f()` (from the only (JavaScript) request from the Square server) however the other browsers return the following:

```
SqPaymentForm.isSupportedBrowser
()
​length: 0
​name: "bound "
​<prototype>: function ()
```

I'm focusing my efforts on determining how browsers are "supported" by the convolutedly minimized code from Square.

---

**Update 2**

The `SqPaymentForm.isSupportedBrowser()` function returns true in Chrome *and* Waterfox. Going off of this documentation (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/setup#step-4-render-sqpaymentform) I receive the following error:

> paymentForm is not defined.

There is some ambiguity in the troubleshooting I did though after roughly an hour I decided to use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
 sqPaymentForm.build();
 sqPaymentForm.recalculateSize();
},2000);
```

...and it worked. So apparently either the Square developers specifically test with Chrome and/or Chrome will either wait until the method exists and execute it or it's load-related timing is somehow better.

So I would like to now ask: how do I adjust my code to *not* require having to rely on `setTimeout`?

Comment: Are you currently referencing any other scripts? If so, can you temporarily disable them to see if the payment form loads? I've personally tested on both Firefox 56 and 64 on localhost and successfully got the payment form to load.

Comment: @sjosey Yes. I updated the bottom of the post and it appears that the browsers that aren't working aren't passing some oddball compatibility test. Linking back to the GitBug bug report: https://github.com/square/connect-api-specification/issues/131.